# Deshabilidar todo un formulario con un boton Angular

Tags: angular

en primera instancia este es mi código, es básicamente una cámara y quería hacer obligatorio tomar la foto para poder escribir en las demás casillas.

De modo que triggerSnapshot(); tomara la foto y quisiera que todos los input se  habilitaran nuevamente, una vez teniendo webcamImage que es el valor de la imagen

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="registroModal">Registro vehículo</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="camera" *ngIf="showWebcam">
                <webcam [height]="400" [width]="400" [trigger]="triggerObservable" (imageCapture)="handleImage($event)"
                    *ngIf="showWebcam" [videoOptions]="videoOptions" [imageQuality]="1"
                    (cameraSwitched)="cameraWasSwitched($event)" (initError)="handleInitError($event)"></webcam>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" (click)="triggerSnapshot();">Tomar
                    foto</button>
            </div>
            <div class="camera" *ngIf="webcamImage">
                <img [width]="400" [src]="webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <form class="row" action="" method="POST">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="id" placeholder="Id Usuario"
                        [attr.disabled]="!webcamImage" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"
                        [attr.disabled]="!webcamImage" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" [value]="color" [(colorPicker)]="color" [style.background]="color"
                        [cpPosition]="'bottom'" [cpAlphaChannel]="'disabled'" placeholder="Color"
                        [attr.disabled]="!webcamImage" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Matricula" name="matricula"
                        [attr.disabled]="!webcamImage" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Tipo de Vehiculo" name="tipo"
                        [attr.disabled]="!webcamImage" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Modelo" name="modelo"
                        [attr.disabled]="!webcamImage" />
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
            (click)="toggleWebcam();modal.close('Save click')">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar cambios</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

También tengo el script de lo que es el component.js

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { WebcamImage, WebcamInitError, WebcamUtil } from 'ngx-webcam';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  public color: String;
  public closeResult: String;
  public myInnerHeight: Number = window.innerHeight - (window.innerHeight * .30);
  public isMenuCollapsed: Boolean = true;
  public showWebcam: Boolean;
  // public allowCameraSwitch: Boolean = true;
  public multipleWebcamsAvailable: Boolean = false;
  public deviceId: string;
  public videoOptions: MediaTrackConstraints = {
    // width: {ideal: 1024},
    // height: {ideal: 576}
  };
  public errorsCamera: WebcamInitError[] = [];
  public webcamImage: WebcamImage = null;
  private trigger: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(
    private _modalService: NgbModal
  ) { }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }

  public open(content): void {
    this.color = '#ffffff';
    this.showWebcam = true;
    this.webcamImage = null;
    this._modalService.open(content, { ariaLabelledBy: 'registroModal', size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static' }).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  public toggleWebcam(): void {
    this.showWebcam = !this.showWebcam;
  }

  public triggerSnapshot(): void {
    this.trigger.next();
    this.toggleWebcam();
  }

  public handleInitError(error: WebcamInitError): void {
    this.errorsCamera.push(error);
  }

  public handleImage(webcamImage: WebcamImage): void {
    console.info('received webcam image', webcamImage);
    this.webcamImage = webcamImage;
  }

  public cameraWasSwitched(deviceId: string): void {
    console.log('active device: ' + deviceId);
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
  }

  public get triggerObservable(): Observable<void> {
    return this.trigger.asObservable();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    WebcamUtil.getAvailableVideoInputs()
      .then((mediaDevices: MediaDeviceInfo[]) => {
        this.multipleWebcamsAvailable = mediaDevices && mediaDevices.length > 1;
      });
  }
}
```

Agradecería bastante si alguien sabe la forma en la que se pudiera deshabilitar todo el formulario

También tengo otra pregunta, una vez teniendo la imagen ¿Se necesita poner como parte del formulario, o una vez teniéndola en la lógica se puede envíar o es ahi mismo dónde se guarda?

Había entendido que existía [attr.disabled] pero si funciona, pero solo para deshabilitar, no habilita nuevamente :c

Comment: No necesitas `[attr.disabled]`; esto se usa **solo en etiquetas que no poseen un atributo `disabled`**. En tu caso, estás usando `input`s, por ende, solo necesitas `[disabled]="!webcamImage"`. Respecto a `handleImage`, ¿Se está ejecutando? ¿Qué te muestra el console.log?

Comment: Ya había puesto [disabled]="!webcamImage" como una de mis opciones, pero no funciona, [attr.disabled]="!webcamImage ? '' : null" pero esto sí, no sé a qué se deba :c

Answer (score 0):

Es tan fácil como esto:

```
[attr.disabled]="!webcamImage ? '' : null"
```